# Remove jquery script from a control

Tags: c#, jquery

I am coding a galery in jquery.
I have an image zoom tool that is put on a main image on an image_preload event.
I have smaller images that when clicked swaps the main image out with the one that is clicked. The new image is now the main image.

The problem is that the zoom tool is still picking up the old image even though in firebug it says that the new image was loaded into the zoomer.

I want to remove the code that i have on the main image when the switch is made and then put it back on. I'm thinking this will update the zoomer.

i have

```
$('.MYCLASS').jqzoom();
```

so can i do something like

```
$('.MYCLASS').jqzoom().Remove();
```

Thanks any help is appreciated

Comment: The 'official' jQuery plugin tutorial adds a `destroy` option. If this plugin used one, it would be called like `$('.MYCLASS').jqzoom('destroy')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to know what the function does in order to reverse its effects. It might be that the plugin provides a `remove` function, but I doubt that it would work in your instance.

One suggestion might be to simply `clone` the `$('.MYCLASS')` element and delete the original which has been bound with the `jqzoom()` plugin.

Comment: Good man, i used your idea but instead of cloning i appended the same stuff back in and that worked